# Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 layout switcher shortcut does not rotate

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, dconf, gsettings, ubuntu-budgie

Recently I installed Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 on my Dell XPS15, but currently I am having an issue with layout switching.

I've added 3 layouts to my system. Using default key combination to switch layout, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, it behaves somehow weird when I switch layouts; on key down <kbd>Super</kbd>, pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>, layout is switched as expected. Subsequent repeated pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> does nothing however. Only after releasing <kbd>Super</kbd> and pressing the same combination again allows me to switch to next layout.

I checked with other distros (Antergos KDE, Solus Budgie), and there it *does* work as expected. Maybe someone knows how to make switch layout shortcut work like on other systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu Budgie, the switching layout shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should work the same as what you are used to. However there seems to be a

#### Conflicting dconf key

The default dconf value for `/desktop/ibus/general/hotkey/triggers` Is similar to the layout- switch shortcut, which causes your issue.

#### Fix

To fix, run in a terminal window:

```
dconf write /desktop/ibus/general/hotkey/triggers "@as []"
```

and it should work as expected again.

#### Note

The issue will be fixed soon in Budgie with a gsettings override.

---

#### Additional information

Not directly what you asked for, but since you are using 17.10 and using multiple layouts, it might be useful to install the ***Keyboard Auto Switch***, which automatically changes the layout, depending on the application:

[image]

In UB 17.10, activate backports in Budgie Welcome, update and install the applet. In 18.04, it will be available by default in Budgie Welcome.